# YA book about a young girl who is kidnapped by fairy people

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I remember very little about this book, but I remember it featured a lot of eerie black and white pencil illustrations. I think it was about a young girl who is kidnapped by people who live under the hills. Its the story of her stay with them and how she escapes. I remember the illustration of a woman watching her from the woods. Any advice on what book this is?

Comment: When did you read it? Was it new then, or do you know when it was first published??

Comment: Was it a picture book or a novel with pictures?

Comment: If you want to thank Metamaterial girl for correctly identifying the book, mark her answer as "accepted" (click the check mark next to her answer to turn it green) so others can know that she correctly identified the book.  Both you and her will gain reputation for it.

Answer (score 9):

Could it possibly be [The Perilous Gard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Perilous_Gard), by Elizabeth Marie Pope? The story is set in early Elizabethan England, and the main character, Kate Sutton, is given to the Old Ones after she learns of their existence. The story is based loosely on the story of Tam Lin, in which she saves her love interest from being sacrificed as a teind to the old gods. The version I have is only a paperback without illustrations, but it is a later printing; the original 1971 edition may have had pictures.

Comment: That does sound like The Perilous Gard. I have an older copy  with b&w illustrations by Richard Cuffari, one of which shows the Lady in the woods.

Comment: yes! Its the Perilous Gard! Thank you so much! I just bought the book and read it. It was amazing!

Comment: Should you return, @JenessaWillett, you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark beside it.