# Looking for a book where people in a well have a little girl and her older sister goes in to save her

Tags: story-identification

It's a fictional novel about a little girl that falls into a well (I don't remember what happens to her) or is taken down into the well by the people that live down there, sortof as a offering. Her big sister goes into the well. They make her stay there, sleep in a cave, no light.

The people that live down there use markings along the tunnel walls to navigate. The big sister eventually learns to interpret these markings and starts to plan her escape.

Somewhere along the way a handsome young man (as is bound to happen) decides to save her and gets himself caught by the people in the well. The well people dress him up in fancy clothes and a jeweled, gold mask and put him on a horse as an offering to their fictional pagan gods. The big sister character ends up saving him.

Comment: So is this fantasy or science fiction?

Comment: This was my question.. I can't comment.. It's a fantasy novel, not science fiction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [YA book about a young girl who is kidnapped by fairy people](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33463/ya-book-about-a-young-girl-who-is-kidnapped-by-fairy-people)

Comment: Sometimes things go a little weird with the authentication for unregistered accounts (like the account that posted this question). You should be able to follow the instructions [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20528/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-account) to fix this

Comment: @Metamaterialgirl - WE DON'T CLOSE STORY ID QUESTIONS AS DUPLICATES UNLESS BOTH OF THEM HAVE ACCEPTED ANSWERS.

Comment: @Metamaterialgirl - http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance

Comment: @WadCheber Is 'vote to close' the same as closing in this instance? Voting to close was recommended when I did a search for the proper procedure for dupes here: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6600/answering-a-duplicate-question. Don't think I have the power to close a question at my user level.

Comment: @Metamaterialgirl - Yes, site policy says that we shouldn't vote to close story id questions unless the new question and the old question both have accepted answers.

Comment: @WadCheber Will do in future.

Answer (score 3):

This is a duplicate question, but the answer is [The Perilous Gard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Perilous_Gard), by Elizabeth Marie Pope.